# Is there a way to determine which solutions are extraneous without plugging them into the original equation.?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I was wondering if there is a way that you can determine which solutions of an equation are extraneous to the original equation or not, without plugging them back into the original equation.

Comment: Yes, before you solve an equation, define the intervals were possible solutions can lie using domains and ranges of involved functions (i.e. I can look at $\sqrt{x+1}=-1$ and say that it has no solutions because a square root cannot be negative)

Comment: @Vasya: Perhaps you could convert your comment into an answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to know if there is a extraneous solution in a radical expression](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2150704/how-to-know-if-there-is-a-extraneous-solution-in-a-radical-expression)